# What does WT_EXECUTEINUITHREAD do?

Tags: winapi, threadpool, queueuserworkitem

What does the `WT_EXECUTEINUITHREAD` flag for the [`QueueUserWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684957.aspx) function do?

Comment: It invokes undocumented behavior, which means it probably breaks on a future version (or Service Pack) of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be explained [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140806040035/https://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2007/10/05/38830).

According to that comment, `NtQueueApcThread` is used to schedule a procedure to be executed the next time your thread enters an alertable wait.

Comment: How is that different from any of the other flags?

Comment: @Mehrdad: The other flags start new threads, or queue a procedure to the thread pool.

Comment: Well, more specifically, I guess I meant how is it different from `WT_EXECUTEINIOTHREAD`? The link you posted has no information specifically on `WT_EXECUTEINUITHREAD`, only a general description on the "ExecuteInXThread" flags...

Comment: @Mehrdad: If you read the MSDN page linked in the question, `WT_EXECUTEINIOTHREAD` is defunct.  But, in XP and earlier, it queued the procedure to an I/O worker thread, not the thread pool, but also not the caller.

Comment: So do you mean it's exactly the same thing as `QueueUserAPC`?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I mean some users observed it to be the same.  But since it's undocumented, the behavior is subject to change at any time.